# Calculator app made in Java (ver2)

Tags: java, android, calculator

A few days ago, I uploaded my first version of my calculator app I made in android studio. I got some great some feedback on it and tried to improve my app as much as I could.

changes/new featres:

- Implemented a delete button
- optimized the way, everything is calculated
- Made a seperate class for the calculator

Here u can see how the app looks [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INCmx.png)

Here is the code from the my `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.calculatormk2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calculator calculatorMain = new Calculator();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onNumberClick(View view) {
        calculatorMain.addDigitToInput(getTextFrom(view));
        updateTextView();
    }

    public void onOperatorClick(View view) {
        calculatorMain.addOperatorToInput(getTextFrom(view));
        updateTextView();
    }

    public void onEqualsClick(View v) {
        TextView mainOutput = findViewById(R.id.mainOutput);
        mainOutput.setText(calculatorMain.calculate());
    }

    public void onDeleteClick(View v) {
        calculatorMain.delete();
        updateTextView();
    }

    public String getTextFrom(View v) {
        return ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    }

    public void updateTextView() {
        TextView mainOutput = findViewById(R.id.mainOutput);
        mainOutput.setText(calculatorMain.getInput());
    }
}
```

And here is the code from my `Calculator.java`

```
package com.example.calculatormk2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Calculator {
    private StringBuilder inputAsText = new StringBuilder();
    private ArrayList inputAsArrayList;

    public void addDigitToInput(String digit) {
        inputAsText.append(digit);
    }

    public void addOperatorToInput(String operator) {
        inputAsText.append(" ").append(operator).append(" ");
    }

    public void delete() {
        if (inputAsText.length() != 0) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(inputAsText.charAt(inputAsText.length() - 1))) {
                inputAsText.deleteCharAt(inputAsText.length() - 1);
                inputAsText.deleteCharAt(inputAsText.length() - 1);
                inputAsText.deleteCharAt(inputAsText.length() - 1);
            } else {
                inputAsText.deleteCharAt(inputAsText.length() - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearInput() {
        inputAsText.delete(0, inputAsText.length());
        inputAsArrayList.clear();
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return this.inputAsText.toString();
    }

    public String calculate() {
        String[] tmpArray = inputAsText.toString().split(" ");
        inputAsArrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(tmpArray));
        inputAsArrayList = calculateFor("x", "÷");
        inputAsArrayList = calculateFor("+", "-");
        String answer = String.valueOf(inputAsArrayList.get(0));
        clearInput();
        return answer;
    }

    public ArrayList calculateFor(String operator1, String operator2) {
        while (inputAsArrayList.contains(operator1) || inputAsArrayList.contains(operator2)) {

            int indexOperator1 = inputAsArrayList.indexOf(operator1);
            int indexOperator2 = inputAsArrayList.indexOf(operator2);
            int indexOperatorMain = Math.min(indexOperator1, indexOperator2);

            if (indexOperator1 == -1) {
                indexOperatorMain = indexOperator2;
            } else if (indexOperator2 == -1) {
                indexOperatorMain = indexOperator1;
            }

            String operatorMain = inputAsArrayList.get(indexOperatorMain).toString();

            double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(inputAsArrayList.get(indexOperatorMain - 1).toString());
            double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(inputAsArrayList.get(indexOperatorMain + 1).toString());

            double answer = calculateSegment(firstNumber, secondNumber, operatorMain);

            inputAsArrayList.remove(indexOperatorMain - 1);
            inputAsArrayList.remove(indexOperatorMain - 1);
            inputAsArrayList.remove(indexOperatorMain - 1);
            inputAsArrayList.add(indexOperatorMain - 1, answer);
        }
        return inputAsArrayList;
    }

    public double calculateSegment(double fNumber, double sNumber, String o) {
        switch (o) {
            case "x":
                return fNumber * sNumber;
            case "÷":
                return fNumber / sNumber;
            case "+":
                return fNumber + sNumber;
            default:
                return fNumber - sNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if I want to make a 3rd version or move on to another project. (after ive learned more about android development) For a 3rd version, I really would like to implement a history that keeps track of all the calculations and answers and possibly also allow the ability to use a square root.

One thing I could not figure out, is how to implement multithreading in my app. I wanted to calculate the answers on a different thread. (Start a new thread at the `calculate()` function) But I didnt know how to return my answer. This probably is useless because the calculations doenst even take 1 second, but it would be some great practise for later projects. Anyways, any feedback/suggestions on my app are welcome. Thanks for reading!

(Git repository: [https://github.com/PhilipNousPXL/Calculator-mk2.git](https://github.com/PhilipNousPXL/Calculator-mk2/tree/306e28a6242a5e5d4875a9041101e3ba96cceec9))

Comment: this looks much better than your previous Code... Especially your `MainActivity` ;-)

Comment: using `List<Strings>` as data model is ambigous - you should use an more OOP-approach. look at [this tutorial](https://www.bemyaficionado.com/basic-calculator-leetcode-problem-using-object-oriented-programming-in-java/) to see some objects - where you have strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for sharing your progress - looks far better than v1, gratulations :-)

### about history

instead of a mere result-history i would advise you to create an **input-history**. Other people have already struggles with such an challange and created an **[Command Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)** from the [GoF (Gang of four)](https://springframework.guru/gang-of-four-design-patterns/). Put your commands on a stack and you have a history - includng undo/redo!

side note

- A Command would help you to stick with the [Separation of Concerns](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC) since you would put these part of your code together that belong together.
- A Command would help you to stick with the [Open Closed Principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Open_Closed_Principle) since it would be very easy to create other command (as mentioned from you: a *square root command*?!)

### about concurrency

if you have a time consuming process that should run aside from your GUI thread (in android) you should have a closer look at the [Executors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) and [Handlers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) (a very small tutorial is found [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-asynctask/)) - i am sorry that i cannot provide any details before you have tried to implement it.

### OOP calculator

well that might be an never endig story, see [this articel](https://www.bemyaficionado.com/basic-calculator-leetcode-problem-using-object-oriented-programming-in-java/) about oop calculator.

> This is a *medium difficulty* problem in Leetcode. This is medium only if you are talking in *terms of algorithm and time complexity*. **But** let’s say you have to build a calculator for an enterprise. The calculator that will be **extensible, maintainable and optimized** at the same time.

So maybe this might be too much for now (since you said you are rather novice, first year? or so?)

**But** with an OOP approach you could at least try to get **rid of your input model** `ArrayList<String> inputAsArrayList` - which is really a pain.

### cool stuff

you really did clean up your `MainActivity` - now it really looks cool and you may be very proud of you in doing it this way!!! keep up that spirit!!